# Knowing when the UI is ready in React / Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, react-redux

I would like to know how long it takes my app to become "ready" for the user to interact with it. The timeline of the app loading includes the following:

1. DOM load.
2. Initial React render.
3. HTTP calls triggered from various `componentDidMount()`s
4. HTTP calls return. Redux state is updated with HTTP responses.
5. React renders with new values from HTTP responses.
6. All initial loading is complete. The user is ready to interact with the app.

At the end of this process, I'd like to fire a tracking event to record the value of `window.performance.now()`.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. React's component system does a good job of decoupling various parts of the UI. In this case, it, unfortunately, means that I'm not going to have one easy place to check to know "has everything been rendered with the new data".

Things I've tried or considered:

1. Look for a React lifecycle hook that tells me if any child is updating. Something like `componentOrAnyChildDidUpdate()`. I don't think this exists, and it may be counter to the React philosophy.
2. Hack together an `anyChildDidUpdate()` lifecycle hook via `context` and making every component in my app either subclass a helper abstract base class or be wrapped in a higher-order component. This seems bad because `context` is an [experimental API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).
3. Subscribe to the Redux state via `store.subscribe()`. Update the Redux state to have an explicit record of whether all the HTTP calls have returned. Once all the HTTP calls have returned, and React is finished re-rendering, then I know to fire the tracking callback. The problem is knowing when React is finished re-rendering. It would work if my `store.subscribe()` the callback was guaranteed to be executed synchronously after `react-redux`'s callback. But that is not the case.

Is there a good way to do this in React?

Comment: Why not have all of these API calls in one redux "APP_START" action?

Comment: A redux action by itself won't be enough. I want to know when the app has finished rendering in response to a redux action.

Comment: @NickHeiner You can track a list of all self contained static components in your redux state, then once you've used 3. to establish the point when the state is finalized, you wait for every tracked component to dispatch a redux action indicating rendering is complete.

Comment: @NickHeiner are you using any redux middleware to catch the HTTP calls? like `redux-promise`,  `redux-saga`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is not a universally good way to do this in React, this is "logic" that is related with the structure of your application.

I wanted to display a loader when navigating from one page to another in Single Page Application(SPA) written in react and I faced a similar problem not knowing when to stop displaying it and if all the components in the new page have completed their API calls/renders.

The way I resolved it was:

1) I removed all my API calls from inside my components.

2) Create a Page component to wrap all the components included in that    page(invoked by your react router).

3) Perform all requests required for your components simultaneously on    navigation(in my case while displaying the loader). For each request that completes, create a promise and inside it create your component dynamically using React.createElement. Pass to the component created the request response and the promise handler as props.

4) Resolve the promise in your component's `componentDidMount`.

5) Once all the promises are resolved you know the "page" is ready and you    can record the value of `window.performance.now()`.

It is hard to provide a minimal code example without a lot of out of context code since this code is spread across the application.

Comment: > _I'm afraid there is not a universally good way to do this in React_ - in React - no. In redux - possible. In idiomatic redux - easy. Redux is given in OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do what you're asking - but off the top of my head I would do the following:

• Create a perf reducer and call `performance.now()` right before I make the redux store and add the value to the initial state.

```
{ perf: { start: '...', end: '...' } }
```

• Track loading status of initial HTTP requests in a loaded reducer.

```
{ loaded: { request1: false, request2: false, request3: false } }
```

• Connect top level component to loaded reducer and check if all requests are complete in componentDidUpdate. If true add end value to perf reducer.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!prevProps.loadingComplete && this.props.loadingComplete) {
      this.props.updatePerf(performance.now());
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loadingComplete: state.loaded.every(item => item),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updatePerf(time) {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_ENDING_PERF', payload: time });
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

In our project, we use redux and a couple of actions - trigger, request, success, error.

"Trigger" calls request and throw loading: true into our "smart" component
"Request" fetch data and throw them into Success/Error
"Success", tells us that everything is fine and data loaded and throw { loading: false, data }

On success/error, we always know that is happening with our application

And of course you can use componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {} and check loading flag and data in your component

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `react-addons-perf`

That's how I benchmark my apps usually:

Basically you want to start measuring when your component starts updating and stop the measurement after the lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate()`.

```
import Perf from 'react-addons-perf'

componentWillMount() {
  window.performance.mark('My app');
 }
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(window.performance.now('My app'));
  Perf.start()
  // ... do your HTTP requests
}
componentDidUpdate() {
 Perf.stop();
 Perf.printInclusive();
}
```

Like that you will track your component initial render + your component updates.

Hope it helps

Comment: Do NOT use react-addons-perf since it is deprecated and no longer works with the latest version of react(which is 16.0.0).

Comment: That's correct if you use React 16. Still valid if you are not going to upgrade (even if you should). Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Two steps to achieve this.

**Track all HTTP-requests via actions**

Simple counter **in redux state** would be enough, that increments on start of request and decrements on success or fail (all via appropriate actions).
No `window.dirty.stuff` here in front of Dan Abramov.

**Track all *`connect`ed* components**

`componentDidUpdate` method indicates that all children finished rendering. This can be achieved without much boilerplate with `recompose`'s `lifecycle` HOC. Right place to start tracking re-render might be `sCU` method or just `cWRP` if you use `recompose`s `shouldUpdate` or `reselect` already - since we won't track components that didn't update.

Note that all is assuming idiomatic react/redux app, no tricky side-effects or animations. For example, if some child component somewhere deep in the hierarchy fires its own AJAX request, say on `cDM`, not via redux action. This way you have to track them too, BUT no one can be sure if they imply any re-renders.
Tracking such behaviors is still possible, just might require more effort.

Answer (score 0):

from a design POV, in my opinion being ready or not is a user presentation property and so should be handled by react components alone.

for example, you may later decide to allow the user to interact with some part of your UI while some other parts are still loading, or you may decide that some components should allow the user to interact before the data model is ready, etc ... in other words, it's a (react) component responsability to tell if/when it's ready or not and nobody else.

That is, all 'waitable' components could expose an *onLoad*-like prop to be passed up the react tree; the root component would then coordinate the result by changing the tree down stream accordingly by propagating the appropriate props down to leaves.

This could be implemented by writing a mixin/high order component to incapsulate the "readyness update" logic.